# How can I share a Microsoft office form so only specific people have access?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

I would like to share a link to a Microsoft office form, such that only a subset of people from the organisation (a large subset, so I can't type them one by one, rather upload or copy paste a list) can access the form. Is that possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This very much depends on how you wish to allow access. The easiest way would be to share the file via OneDrive. You can create a shareable link to your document and then select the permissions those accessing your file should have. Once that is selected, you will hasve the opportunity to send the link via email to all the people that you would like it to be sent to. Here's a link to Microsoft's website with detailed instructions: [Microsoft Collaberation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-your-documents-651e1cb9-9a51-46dc-8d32-bdb7d928eedd)

You should be able to do this with any MS Office program.